# How to emit an item from first observable then 4 items from second observable?

Tags: functional-programming, rx-java, rxjs, reactive-programming, rx-java2

Let's say I have two array lists, I want to emit an item from the first list then 4 items from the second list and combine them into a third observable which emits the result of this operator. If the second list has less than 4 items, then emit all items remaining from this list.[image]

O1: A, B, C, D 
O2: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14

So the result will be : A1234    B5678   C9101112   D1314

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haven't checked by a compiler, it's just something I can think of:

```
Observable<T> o1 = ...
Observable<T> o2 = ...

Observable<T> o3 = o1.zip(o2.buffer(4), (a, b) -> {
  List<T> contents = new ArrayList<>();
  contents.add(a);
  contents.addAll(b);
  return contents;
}).flatMap(list -> Observable.from(list));
```

1. `buffer` the second `Observable` (the one that you want to take chunks of 4 of)
2. `zip` it with the first `Observable`, and create a single `List<T>` from the 2
3. `flatMap` the `Observable<List<T>>` into `Observable<T>`
4. Also mind that I assume that both of your `Observable`s are of the same type.

Comment: thank you, would buffer of 4 work if the list 2 no longer has 4 items left to emit?

Comment: Sure just read the docs of `buffer`: _buffer(count) emits non-overlapping buffers in the form of Lists, each of which contains at most count items from the source Observable (the final emitted List may have fewer than count items)._